# Why does "un" switch to "de" when negating?

Tags: articles, négation

> Est-ce quelqu'un m'a envoyé un message?
>
> Non, personne ne t'a envoyé de message.

Why is "un" used when asking the question and "de" used when answering?

Answer (score 4):

Often, indefinite articles (un/une/des) change to « de » when negated, even if it's plural.

> J'ai vu **un** chien chez toi / Je **n'ai pas vu de** chien chez toi
>
> Tu veux **une** pastèque fraîche ? / Tu **ne veux pas de** pastèque fraîche ?
>
> Il a **des** vacances chaque mois / Il **n'a
> pas de** vacances chaque mois

Comment: « Il fait des vacances chaque mois / Il ne fait pas de vacances chaque mois »

This is incorrect. Would you mean :

Il a des vacances chaque mois / Il n’a pas de vacances chaque mois ?

Comment: @Stéphane merci, j'ai corrigé la phrase !